# Peer Based Validation in MongoDB Schema

Tags: mongodb, validation, mongodb-schema

I am using MongoDB Schema to validate the data inserted into the database. I would like to have peer based validation similar to `Joi.when()` in [Joi](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.2.1#anywhencondition-options).
Here is how the data looks like:

```
first:"Teddy",
last:"Bear"
```

How would I make *last* `required` and have `maxLength:10` only if the *first* is not null? I need something that is equivalent to this in [MongoDB jsonSchema](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#op._S_jsonSchema):

```
last: Joi.string().when('first', { is: null, then: Joi.required().max(10), otherwise:Joi.forbidden() }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Conditional validation if-then-else was introduced in [draft-07](https://json-schema.org/draft-07/json-schema-release-notes.html) a year ago. Mongo uses 7 years old [draft-04](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-04) of json schema.

Comment: Thanks. I think I could only do validation in application layer for now.